# How run a background process?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I am searching for a way to background apps using `creationflags` with `subprocess` module. I tried `notepad` as an example but notepad does pop up and it is not a background process is there any other way to achieve this goal?

You can use any app you like to test with I care about the way not the app.

```
import subprocess
import time 


def call_notepad():
    CREATE_NO_WINDOW = 0x08000000
    subprocess.call('notepad', creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
    print (time.time())
    return 

call_notepad()
```

Comment: `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` is only for console applications, so it wont do anything for something like notepad.

Comment: what to use for none console apps?